# cakephp creating a form with user inputs

Tags: forms, cakephp, formhelper

im trying to create a view where a user has selected a template number that they have created are then taken to the next page where it spits out the fields that they have created for that template. I have my sql statements doing what I want them to do but I am unsure on how to get the form printing out these `custom` fields `default_values` into the input  boxes

invoices table contains `id sender_id receiver_id template_id`
fields table contains `id name default_value active template_id`

```
invoices hambt fields
fields hambt invoices
```

there join table is fields_invoices, it contains `id invoice_id field_id entered value`

i am unsure how to get the id's from the invoice table and field table  to save to the join table

```
    public function create($id)
    {   
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Create Invoice');
    $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'homestyle');
    $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogoHome.png');   
    $this->layout='home_layout';

     if (!is_numeric($id)) throw new BadMethodCallException('I need an ID');
     $this->Invoice->id = $id;
     if (!$this->Invoice->exists()) throw new NotFoundException('Invalid ID');

    $this->set('invoice_id',$id);

    $names = $this->Invoice->find('list',array(
    'fields'=>array('template_id'),
    'conditions'=>array('id'=>$id)));

    $fields = $this->Field->find('list', array(
     'conditions'=>array(
     'template_id'=>$names)));

    $this->set('field',$fields);

    $this->set('name',$names);

    if(empty($this->data)){
        $this->data= $this->Field->read($fields);
    } 
    else{
        if(($this->Field->save($this->data)))
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('The field has been updated');
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'invoices', 'action'=>'index'));

        }
        }
}
```

here is the view

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('fields_invoices'); ?>
    <?php foreach ($field as $fields): ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->Input($fields); ?>
    <?php endforeach ;?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->End('Submit');?>
```

now i am unsure on how to code the view properly and get it so that it prints out the `default_variables` in the `fields` table into the `input boxes`. any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Can you debug the $fields array for us?

You can specify what you want in your auto-generated input field...

ie: $this->Form->input('field_name',array('label'=>'whatever you want to call it','value'=>'value'));